# Algorithm to find a filtered set of combinations

Tags: python, combinatorics

I'm using Python to find a filtered set of combinations of pairs computed via a Cartesian product. I can calculate what I need using a heuristic algorithm but it feels clunky and I'm afraid I'm reinventing something that is probably a known and solved math concept for which better algorithms exist.

Here's a example:

Assume I have an order for **2** products, A and B, and I have inventory in **3** warehouses (1,2,3). I'd like to compute all possible ways I can ship this order, in total or in part, from one of my 3 warehouses. Assume unlimited inventory, so no constraints. The resulting list of possible ways will ultimately be fed into an optimization routine to minimize shipping costs etc. However, to start I'd like to find a more elegant (and likely more scalable) way to compute the list of possible fulfillment options.

Here's what I have so far. Any ideas on how this can be solved in more mathematically efficient way would be much appreciated. I'm not looking for ways to avoid the `for` loop, I know I can probably use broadcasting. Thanks!

```
from itertools import *

# Products in order
P = ['A', 'B'] 

# Possible warehouses
W = ['1', '2', '3'] 

# Get the Cartesian product of all products in the order
# and all warehouses
PW = list(product(P, W))
```

Result:

```
[('A', '1'), 
 ('A', '2'), 
 ('A', '3'), 
 ('B', '1'), 
 ('B', '2'), 
 ('B', '3')]
```

Then, compute the possible combinations of these product/warehouse pairs

```
pwc = list(combinations(PW, 2))
```

Result:

```
[(('A', '1'), ('A', '2')),
 (('A', '1'), ('A', '3')),
 (('A', '1'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '1'), ('B', '2')),
 (('A', '1'), ('B', '3')),
 (('A', '2'), ('A', '3')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '2')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '3')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '2')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '3')),
 (('B', '1'), ('B', '2')),
 (('B', '1'), ('B', '3')),
 (('B', '2'), ('B', '3'))]
```

Lastly, filter out any combinations where we would ship the same product from a different warehouses:

```
[u for u in pwc if ((u[0][0] != u[1][0]) and (u[0][1] != u[1][1]))]
```

Result:

```
[(('A', '1'), ('B', '2')),
 (('A', '1'), ('B', '3')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '3')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '2'))]
```

So, is there such a thing as a "filtered cartesian join combination"?

(Hope this all makes sense!)

Comment: Just by the way here, but `&` in Python is a bitwise operator. You're probably looking for the plain old `and` keyword.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 got it, thx! doesn't seem to change the result, thankfully...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this one-liner solves your problem:

```
from itertools import permutations, repeat
[tuple(zip(x, y)) for x, y in zip(repeat('AB'), permutations('123', 2))]
```

Output:

```
[(('A', '1'), ('B', '2')),
 (('A', '1'), ('B', '3')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '3')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '2'))]
```

The difference between this and your method is that you generate all and then filter, while I found a pattern in your expected output and came  up with this method.

If anyone can see a better way to simplify this, be welcome to suggest it.

Comment: I'm digging this already, thanks for getting a hang of what I'm trying to do here so quickly! Any idea if there's a term for what this does? I feel like this is a common problem and should have a common name, but my Google has failed me.

Comment: @ClausHerther I'm not too sure, but it seems like you are just taking all possible permutations of `'1', '2', '3'` and "labeling" the first with `'A'` and the second with `'B'`.

Comment: @ClausHerther Yeah. Also, I just realized you can declare `P` and `W` as `'AB'` and `'123'`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, looking backwards from the output is a clever way to approach this. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tomothy32 Nice!  I took a different appoach.  Filter PW to two groups product those two groups and filter that product where W's are different.  However, this approach is much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from itertools import *

# Products in order
P = ['A', 'B'] 

# Possible warehouses
W = ['1', '2', '3'] 

# Get the Cartesian product of all products in the order
# and all warehouses
PW = list(product(P, W))

# Split PW in two groups based on P then product those groups
u = list(product(*[list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == i, PW)) for i in P]))

# Filter result for where different W's
list(filter(lambda x: x[0][1] != x[1][1], u))
```

Output:

```
[(('A', '1'), ('B', '2')),
 (('A', '1'), ('B', '3')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '2'), ('B', '3')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '1')),
 (('A', '3'), ('B', '2'))]
```